# paypal responsive not working in magento

Tags: paypal

I am working on magento site. i have an issue on payapal ( mobile )responsive regarding. when i click on direct paypal checkout after the redirection desktop view is fine but mobile view is not fine . I do'nt know whats wrong. if you have any solution please message me. please check the snapshorts.

Thank you

Snapshorts

[image: My Current site view (mobile view is not working in magento)]

[image: I want like this]

Comment: what do you mean by `not fine` ? provide the button code/request that you are sending to paypal

Comment: i mean its showing like a desktop view on mobile. where as it should be like mobile. ( responsive )

Comment: <a href="https://www.example.com/paypal/express/start/button/1/" id="ec_shortcut_564bda474bdeb8199e8d0e4f1712cf38" data-action="checkout-form-submit"><img title="Checkout with PayPal" alt="Checkout with PayPal" src="https://www.paypal.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_xpressCheckout.gif"></a>

Comment: any idea about my question ? if you have any solution. please respond me.

Comment: https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/express-checkout/integration-guide/ECOnMobileDevices/

if you use certain parameters in Expres checkout integration, paypal will automatically render desktop view , make sure you are doing it correctly

Answer (score 0):

As stated on [magento official website](http://magento.com/blog/magento-news/magento-enables-responsive-sites-half-time):

> Improved Payment and Financing Options These new Magento product
>   releases also offer better payment and financing options that can help
>   merchants improve conversion and sales. The Bill Me Later service
>   offers customers access to on-the-spot financing, so they can buy now
>   and pay later, with no additional cost to the merchant. Ready-made
>   banner ads and a prominent Bill Me Later button at checkout are
>   included to help promote the new service. Forrester Consulting
>   estimates that merchants offering Bill Me Later see an 18 percent*
>   boost in sales. **Merchants also have an option to offer customers a
>   more streamlined PayPal Express Checkout** experience which
>   automatically tries alternative payment options when a customer’s
>   credit card is rejected to help drive more sales.

Which Magento version do you use?

Starting with [Magento 1.9.1.0](http://merch.docs.magento.com/ce/user_guide/Magento_Community_Edition_User_Guide.html#magento/release-notes-ce-1.9.1.html%3FTocPath%3DAppendices%7C%2520Release%2520Notes%7CPrevious%2520Releases%7C_____3) there is [PayPal Express Checkout](http://magento.com/paypal/express-checkout).

I recommend you to [update Magento to latest version](http://razbakov.com/magento/2015/08/05/install-magento-via-composer.html) and configure PayPal Express Checkout.